# Bind the values in interval basis HTML,Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi here is my code i need to bind the values like,

output :  **test test test**

here is my code but working,

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

    function delayMsg2() {
      var timer = null;

        if (timer == null)
    {

            timer = setInterval(rudy(), 1000);
        }
        else 
        {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    function rudy() 
    {   

   document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML + " test";


    }
  </script>     
     <div>
    <button onclick="delayMsg2();" >Click me!</button>
    <span id="output2"></span>
   </div>
```

what i need to change

Comment: `setInterval(rudy, 1000);`, remove the `()`, or it will be executed right away.

Comment: your timer varible scope is bound to function so this interval will not stop, see my answer with demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference your function rudy directly:

```
timer = setInterval(rudy, 1000);
```

No need to write a closure around, like in the other answers.

Whats wrong with your code? You execute rudy() at the moment your delay2msg is executed and you pass the return value (which is void), to the setInterval() method. Not good :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your setInterval declaration

```
timer = setInterval(function(){rudy()}, 1000);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W2p3n/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Changed your line

```
timer = setInterval(rudy(), 1000);
```

To

```
timer = setInterval(function(){rudy();}, 1000);
```

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Swn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

change your code with this one and this will solve your problem of start/stop interval also.

```
var timer = null;
function delayMsg2() {
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = setInterval(rudy, 1000);
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

function rudy() {   
    document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML + " test";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/codat/1/edit)